# What is the best way to customize a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to create a UITableViewCell that has a similar style a the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle, only it should also have a label to the right of the cell just like detailed text label of UITableViewCellStyleValue1. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You need to create a brand new UITableViewCell. That is the most sane option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's documentation shows how you can customize the cell after it is initialized in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Look at the Customizing Cells section in the guide. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1